# Using Python to analyze PDF files

Tags: pdf, hash, output

I wrote a code that detect malicious pdf files.
what I need to do is the following:

every pdf I scan I want to save its hash value in hash database and the output will be saved in output container, 
so if I have another pdf file to scan I will check its hash value if exists in hash database then I will print the output  from the output container.
but if the hash value doesn't exist so it is added to hash database and the output will be added to the output container.

how could I do that and what the way to link the hash value with the output in the output container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of malicious documents are you worried about? Corrupted files or pdfs with virus in it?

To work with pdf in python you can use
[pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)

Then you can open the file like:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
my_doc = PdfFileReader(file("myfile.pdf", "rb"))
```

This way you will check if it is a valid file.

About the link, it could be made in the database itself?

Comment: I wrote a code that do scanning but what I need is the above